# Angular JS Image Crop Directive

Tags: angularjs, crop

Can anyone recommend a decent image cropper directive for Angularjs?  I've looked at a few out there and can't find much of anything.  Has anyone found one they use that they like?

We currently use angular-file-upload (https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) to upload files so it would be nice if it worked with this.

Comment: I wrote a blog post about comparing some of the here mentioned image crop directives:

https://lingohub.com/blog/2016/03/angularjs-directives-image-cropping/

I also got it working with angular-file-upload, there is also a link in the article with the solution.

Comment: Check ngImgCrop example with PHP to save as PNG image https://www.freakyjolly.com/angularjs-image-crop-directive-with-resize-in-angular-1-x/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you could try [ngImgCrop](https://github.com/alexk111/ngImgCrop) which it's awesome! it's way more than only a image cropper! and I see no issue using it with angular-file-upload!

cheers!

Comment: I looked at this one and it doesn't seem to work well on mobile devices.  When I select an image to crop on my iPhone using Chrome the image gets skewed really bad.  Do you use this for mobile or do you degrade to a different component?

Comment: unfortunately I haven't try it on a mobile device, but you can just not using depending on resolution, or use a fixed size for the image preview, another workaround could be to crop the image on the server side, it's not ideal but you are going to make sure that all the image sizes are going to be consistent

Comment: We are going to go that route.  We will use this directive in our "desktop" layout and then remove it on our "mobile" layouts. This directive seems to work in all the "modern" browsers so it will work for us.

Comment: At the time of this comment, `ngImgCrop` is not compatible with camera uplods from mobile devices.  Just FYI: https://github.com/alexk111/ngImgCrop/issues/40

Comment: It's awesome, except it only crops squares, not rectangles.

Comment: There is a [fork](https://github.com/CrackerakiUA/ngImgCropFullExtended) of `ngImgCrop` which can be used for rectangular crops

Answer (score 6):

I suggest this one https://github.com/koorgoo/ngCropper.
It is built over jquery plugin and has variaty of options to be customized

Answer (score 4):

I am currently using Angular Image crop by Andy's.
Its cool and has good features.

http://andyshora.com/angular-image-cropper.html

Only draw back, it does not support for camera. Rest fine.

Cheers,
-/Sammi

Comment: javascript promise has been used, which wont work in older versions of browsers. Fo eg, it wont work in android 4.4.2 and below

Comment: I guess we are talking about web development in this thread.

Comment: how do you upload cropped image to a server using this andyshora's directive.