# Angular directive for image preview

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I create a preview window for cropping image with `Angular` directive, when I only know the image address?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25935647/2460773

Answer (score 0):

Well, you probably need to load the image using the [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader). Then draw the imageData into a [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) element. The logic to do that has nothing to do with AngularJS but rather pure javascript.